# Do Style Setters support two way bindings (for attached properties)?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, styles

Here's my XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"
                        CanUserResize="True"
                        CanUserSort="True"
                        Header=" Заголовок "
                        SortMemberPath=".">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Helpers:FocusHelper.IsFocused" Value="{Binding IsEnvelopeFocused, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TitleConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding Path="." />
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Language" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

`FocusHelper` starts listening for the changes of IsFocused property. But passing the value to `IsEnvelopeFocused` happens only once.

I cannot find the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the do.
The problem was in the [binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504865/what-is-a-cached-acessor-in-the-context-of-databinding) but I have no idea why.